# Python twisted render PHP

Tags: php, python, get, cgi, twisted

On a web server generated with python twisted is possible to run php pages?

Looking at documentation seems it is possible:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.twcgi.CGIScript.html

I'm stuck at this point, how can I render the files?

```
    class service(resource.Resource):
def getChild(self, name, request):
    self._path = request.prepath[:]
                # Is this an php
    elif request.prepath[0] == 'php':
        return _ShowPHP

    elif (len(self._path) != 1):
        _ServiceError.SetErrorMsg('Invalid path in URL: %s' % self._path)
        return _ServiceError
```

ShowPHP:

```
class ShowPHP(resource.Resource):

isLeaf = True   # This is a resource end point.
def render(self, request):
  #return "Hello, world! I am located at %r." % (request.prepath,)

  class PythScript(twcgi.FilteredScript):
    filter="/usr/bin/php"
    resource = static.File("php") # Points to the perl website
    resource.processors = {".php": ShowPHP} # Files that end with .php
    resource.indexNames = ['index.php']


############################################################
_ShowPHP = ShowPHP()
```

but when point the browser to the php page got this:
Request did not return a string

Request:

```
    <GET /php/index.php HTTP/1.1>
```

Resource:

```
      <service.ShowPHP instance at 0x2943878>
```

Value:

None

Comment: Do you want to actually run PHP within the Python interpreter, or do you just want the results of a PHP page ?  Those are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on my machine, at least, it's necessary to use `php-cgi` and not plain `php` as the executable.  the difference is that with `php-cgi`, the interpreter makes sure it's emitting the correct set of headers to be a proper cgi response:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site

from twisted.web.twcgi import FilteredScript

class PhpPage(FilteredScript):
    filter = "/usr/bin/php-cgi"
    #                  ^^^^^^^

    # deal with cgi.force_redirect parameter by setting it to nothing.
    # you could change your php.ini, too.
    def runProcess(self, env, request, qargs=[]):
        env['REDIRECT_STATUS'] = ''
        return FilteredScript.runProcess(self, env, request, qargs)

resource = PhpPage('./hello.php')
factory = Site(resource)

reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
reactor.run()
```